# Обновление данных на форме WinAPI

Tags: c++, c, многопоточность, winapi

Как можно обновлять текст в **Edit Control** прямо из потока?
У меня не получается, можете подсказать в чем проблема?

Запуск потока:

```
        case IDC_START:
        {       
            hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Add, (void*)0, 0, &ID_THREAD1);

            WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
            MessageBox(hwnd,"","",MB_OK);
            CloseHandle(hThread);


            return FALSE;
        }break;
```

И функция которая в потоке изменит **Edit Control**

```
DWORD WINAPI Add(LPVOID p)
{
    PostMessage(hLog, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"asdsadsadadasdasd");
    return 0;
}
```

Много чего перепробовал, но не помогло.
*P.S* да, знаю, что PostMessage это асинхронный способ поставить сообщение в очередь для его исполнения без задержек, но я не так что-то понимаю, ведь по аналогии с SendMessage должно работать...

Спасибо!

Comment: Потому что с UI лучше работать в родном потоке (во избежание таких вот непредсказуемых проблем) то есть нужно передавать данные в родной поток и там уже обновлять свой Edit Control.

Comment: Не подскажите как их в родной поток передать? ожиданием объекта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сообщение `WM_SETTEXT` должно отправляться синхронно.

> If you send a message in the range below WM_USER to the asynchronous
>   message functions (PostMessage, SendNotifyMessage, and
>   SendMessageCallback), its message parameters **cannot include pointers**.
>   **Otherwise, the operation will fail.** The functions will return before
>   the receiving thread has had a chance to process the message and the
>   sender will free the memory before it is used.

Вообще не вижу смысла использовать `WM_SETTEXT`, если есть `SetWindowText()`

Но если очень хочется асинхронности, то:

```
#define WM_MY_COOL_MESSAGE WM_USER + 123

case WM_MY_COOL_MESSAGE:
   char* msg = (char*)lParam;
   SetWindowTextA(hLog, msg);
   free(msg);

DWORD WINAPI Add(LPVOID p)
{
    PostMessage(hwnd, WM_MY_COOL_MESSAGE, 0, (LPARAM)strdup("asdsadsadadasdasd"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно.